# Image disappears when scrolls to edge of viewport

Tags: jquery, image, parallax

Some of us are wondering why the images in this tutorial demo disappear as soon as they touch the top - scroll slowly on slide 3 in the demo:

http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html

i havent been able to figure it out. the tutorial is here: 
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/

Comment: works fine for me...what are u asking exaclty?

Comment: I can see what you mean, and I agree it shouldn't happen. However my bet is that it has to do with the `stellar` plugin, and to debug that in minified form is going to take a long long time.

Comment: yea that would be hell... the weird thing is that once in a while in chrome it actually *glitches* and works without disappearing

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer: it's the parameter `hideDistantElements` found in stellar.js. You need to change the 0 to a 1, effectively disabling it.

Reference:  https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js/issues/7

Comment: That's really weird, I had to set that same value to 0 to make it work without disappearing images.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and for performance i didn't want to disable hideDistantElements.

I noticed the divs would stay visible if I scrolled to their location (where they would normally dissapear) and reload the page. If this works for you try opening the page in incognito mode as the problem seems to be on the caching end of the website.

I also changed names of all classes named "scroll" to something unique, however I am not sure this made any difference, because that's when I noticed the cache problem.

Hope this helps anyone, at least it worked for me.

Comment: Turns out it still isn't consistent as it doesen't work in safari, guess the only solution is hideDistantElements

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also.
I noticed that the scrolled elements started disappearing too early after a particular div - the difference between that div and the others was that this div had a "float: none" css property.

Try adding `float: left` to the divs you are scrolling.

EDIT: Also, i found the bug occurred if your refresh the page and you are already scrolled half way down the page.
To get around this add the `responsive: true` parameter when instantiating stellar

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here from the author:
https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js-site/issues/1

No need to hideDistantElements. Just set the dimensions of the div/image in your css or html.

Answer (score 0):

Setting div sizes and stellar's options wasn't helpful for me.
Fixed issue using `background-attachment:initial;` for scrolling div.